# What is Middleware in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express, server, request, middleware

I am a beginner in Node JS and I am trying to learn website developement with Node.js and Express. I have found this word: middleware, especially when I was documenting about callback functions and `app.use()` function. What is middleware? What is used for? What is the connection between `app.use()` function and middleware?

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Comment: At its most basic it is code that runs before any router specific logic. Like authentication. So a request comes in and goes throu the auth middleware before ever hitting your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

software that acts as a bridge between an operating system or database and applications, especially on a network. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&client=opera&hs=iH7&q=middleware%20mean&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimtd2xn8HaAhWpDsAKHTYHA_8QBQgjKAA&biw=1326&bih=631)

Middleware is software which lies between an operating system and the applications running on it. Essentially functioning as hidden translation layer, middleware enables communication and data management for distributed applications. [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/overview/what-is-middleware/)

by following the definitions, if we simply check working code:

```
// Creating a course
app.post(‘/api/courses’, (request, response) => {

});

// Getting all the courses
app.get(‘/api/courses’, (request, response) => {

});
```

if you look into this code known as middleware code in express, requesting the data from the server with `request` and respons back that data to the client with `response` variable. This is the bridge between client and the server.

Answer (score 0):

in express, Middleware functions are functions that accepts the request object (`req`), the response object (`res`), and `next` function as argument.

**ex:**

```js
// this middleware will run when user hits `https://yourdomain.com/` with GET method
app.get('/',

  // middleware
  (req, res) => {

    res.send('hello world');
  }
)
```

`app.use()` static method executes the specified middleware(s) for all request

**ex:**

```js
// whenever a user hits a endpoint from your server, this middleware will run first
app.use(

  // middleware 
  (req, res, next) => {
    // do someting

    next() // pass control to the next middleware
  }
)
```